# Use RegisterDeviceNotification() for ALL USB devices

Tags: c++, windows, usb, notifications

I currently have some code that sets up notifications of connected USB HID devices within a Windows Service (written in C++).  The code is as follows:

```
   GUID hidGuid;
   HidD_GetHidGuid(&hidGuid);

   DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;
   ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter));
   NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
   NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
   NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = hidGuid;
   HDEVNOTIFY deviceNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(StatusHandle, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE);
```

A notification is then received via the SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT event. (Remember, this is a Service so no WM_DEVICECHANGE).

I thought I could just specify the DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE flag in the RegisterDeviceNotification() call so it would override dbcc_classguid and get all devices, but it turns out that that flag is not supported on Windows 2000, which is a dealbreaker for me.  Also, I'm guessing that that would return more than just USB devices.

How should I modify this to get *all* USB devices, not just USB HID?  Should it be as simple as just giving a different GUID?  Is there even a GUID for all USB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE (in "usbiodef.h") to watch for all USB devices.

```
  DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;
  ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter));

  NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(NotificationFilter);
  NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
  NotificationFilter.dbcc_reserved = 0;

  NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE;

  HDEVNOTIFY hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE);
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `GUID_DEVCLASS_USB`? (defined in devguid.h, Windows SDK)

Did you mean the `DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES` flag?

Also, I found the following article helpful - it's about device GUIDs vs interface GUIDs:

https://web.archive.org/web/20081227101643/http://blogs.msdn.com/doronh/archive/2006/02/15/532679.aspx